# Debugging Mail.app rules

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

Is there a way to see what Mail.app is doing when it scans messages for rule firing?  I have a rules that download bank statements when I get an email from my bank.  Since I have multiple accounts, I rely on the account number in the email message.  I have a number of rules, each having a filter that says

> Message content contains The statement for your account ending in XXXXX is available online for viewing

where XXXXX is the particular account number.  The problem is that the first rule always fires no matter what account number is in the message.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it to

```
Message content contains 'XXXXX'
```

& add 'Stop evaluating Rules' as your last action in the Rule.

Or, if the number may possibly occur in other emails, make the rule.

```
All 
Message content contains 'The statement for your account ending in'  
Message content contains 'XXXXX'
```

Adding 'Stop evaluating Rules' is a sensible precaution for all rules that should stop at that point.

Comment: The problem is that the XXXXX rule gets fired even when the account number is YYYYYY

Comment: even when the only thing it's looking for is XXX & not the rest of the sentence? & Even when you have a 'stop evaluating' after it? The most common error is evaluating a post *after* it should have been marked as 'completed'.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Tetsujin.  While not resolving the main issue, you have provided a couple of best-practices ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I've been building this rule one entry at a time and testing using **⌘⌥L**.  Things would work for a few runs, but then stop.  It turns out that quitting Mail and restarting will make the rule run just fine (for at least a few more times).